# Getting firebase data based on a value selected in a dropdown

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Thеre is a database with categories, each category has a list of values ​​inside. How can I make it so that when a category is selected, a list of items that fall into the selected category is displayed? Now my category names are displayed. I use RecyclerView.

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        list = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();

        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           // Iterable<DataSnapshot> ProductChild = dataSnapshot1.getChildren();

            ProductModel p = new ProductModel();
            p.setProductName(dataSnapshot1.getKey());

            list.add(p);


        }
        adapter = new ProductAdapter(ProductSelectionActivity.this,list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

[For example, a person chooses the category "Dairy products". A list of products included in the selected category is available.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkM5p.png)

Please tell me, because newbie, just started learning Android and the first time I work with Firebase.